# Change dtype without NA values, or while reading DF in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv with that df.head():

```
marker_name     ars120_pos  snp_bs  ars120_chrn
0   ARS-BFGL-BAC-10172  5342658.0   [A/G]   2.0
1   ARS-BFGL-BAC-1020   6889656.0   [T/C]   14.0
2   ARS-BFGL-BAC-10245  NA          [T/C]   14.0
3   ARS-BFGL-BAC-10345  5105727.0   [A/C]   14.0
4   ARS-BFGL-BAC-10365  25323952.0  [A/C]    NA
```

That DF has few millions rows. I want to change datatype of that floats to int32. 
I tried :

```
ARS1_2 = ARS1_2.astype({'marker_name':'str','ars120_pos':'int32','snp_bs':'str','ars120_chrn':'int32'})
```

But I got

```
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

If I think property it's mean than I cant change NA to integer. And ok. I can drop NA, but in cols I can have a symbol of X Y chromosome "X", "Y" - as string. I know I can change it to int for example 99 and 98 but I want to avoid it.

So my question is:
What is the simplest method to change all float in column to integer?
I tried somethin like

```
if type(value) in col == float:
   value.as_int
```

(it's pseudocode of course, I didn't remember exacly code) but it's didn't work too... And it's just a play with regular if. Maybe I can do it better and simpler in pandas?

I lf similar posts on so but I didin't find nothing for me. Expect that line above.

Comment: maybe [this info](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#gotchas-intna) from the pandas docs is helpful?

Comment: It is possible to have NaN values for integers, follow @MrFuppes link. When you said that your column can contain a X-Y symbol, did you mean in the same column with numerical data ?

Comment: @SmileyProd Yes, in same column, when I want to change floats to int? Can I ommit NA and X/Y and change only float ?

Comment: Because you have strings, I don't think you can work with the `astype` function because it wouldn't succeed in converting the strings. The solution I see is whether to encode the X and Y but you didn't seem to want that, or to create a new column referencing the X, and Y and convert them to NaN in the previous column, and finally do the `astype` function as @Lukasz said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change float column to integer column use this:

```
df[col] = df[col].astype(pd.Int32Dtype()) # For single column - instead col put column name
```

If you want to go through all columns at once:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dtype == np.float:
        df[col] = df[col].astype(pd.Int32Dtype())
```

To check types of columns:

```
df.dtypes

Output:
    marker_name    object
    ars120_pos      Int32
    snp_bs         object
    ars120_chrn     Int32
    dtype: object
```

Comment: I believe the recommended pandas way is to use `select_dtypes()` and `apply()`: `df.select_dtypes(include=['float']).apply(lambda x: x.astype(pd.Int32Dtype()), axis=0)`